# Сапог или сапогов? Турок или турков?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

С сапогами даже более-менее все понятно. Все-таки "пара сапог" как-то лучше ложится на язык. А как быть с "турками"? Много "турок" или "турков"? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В "Новом орфоэпическом словаре" Т.Ф. Ивановой (2008)  форма этих существительных во множественном числе, родительном падеже САПОГ, ТУРОК.

Comment: Автор вопроса, похоже, не знал в какой словарь посмотреть.

Answer (score 3):

> Все-таки "пара сапог" как-то лучше ложится на язык

Но лучше все-таки пользоваться орфоэпическим словарем: у Резниченко (2004г.)- сапОГ, вариант "сапогОВ" - устар.

Answer (score 2):

Существительные м.р на твердый согласный в Р.п. могут иметь основное окончание ОВ и вариантное нулевое окончание.

В случае вариантного нулевого окончания не различаются две формы: один сапог - пара сапог, но для ПАРНЫХ  предметов такое совпадение допускается.

Поэтому краткий вариант в этом случае является НОРМАТИВНЫМ.

Answer (score 1):

СапогОВ

падеж   ед. ч.  мн. ч.

Р.  сапога́ сапого́в

ТурОК

падеж   ед. ч.  мн. ч.

Р.  ту́рка  ту́рок

Помню, что еще учительница русского в школе говорила, что "пара сапог" - это просторечный и безграмотный вариант.

Comment: Зачем столько много? Проблема всегда в употреблении родительного множественного

Comment: >Помню, что еще учительница русского в школе говорила  
  
Спрашивать о том, в какие годы это происходило, было бы нетактично, но вариант "сапогов" устарел уже к середине прошлого века.

Comment: Это происходило примерно в 1986-1987 году (мне сейчас 38 лет).

Comment: @Ларf Не "столько много", а "так много"

Comment: Я думаю, уд кто-кто, f Larf понимает разницу между "столько много" и "так много". Тут, помнится, было некоторое осуждение... от которого и осталась эта реплика. в контексте она выглядела вполне осмысленной иронией. Вот, даль, любители удалять комментарии не перевелись.   
  
А если по сути, не вижу ничего криминального в "столько много". Ну разговорный вариант, не более.

Answer (score 1):

Вся обувь, как правило, имеет в род. п. мн. ч. нулевое окончание: сапог, туфель, тапочек, кроссовок, валенок.

Comment: Имеет в рол. п. ======== Здесь тщательнее надо, и также с другой частью Вопроса — заминка.

Comment: Не только обувь, это свойство парных предметов вообще. Но есть исключения.  *Носков*, например. А *сапоги* потеряли "-ов" совсем недавно.

Answer (score 0):

Как ответил Дантон на предложение бежать? Родину не унесёшь на подошвах сапог (или сапогов).

Answer (score 0):

Ну,во-первых «столько много» не бывает, возможно — «так много»?
А вопрос возник потому, что у Высоцкого «Будет долго казаться зловещим нам скрип сапогов!» Представляете, как будет по правилам?
Или это уже не пара сапог, а множество?
А вот «сапожник — без сапог».

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/39577)

Answer (score -2):

Турки как племя давно уже не единая национальность, а многообразный по их представительству народ, нация, граждане страны. Следовательно, уместнее называть их турчанами. Ответ: плохи оба варианта. Устарели.

Устарели и оба варианта из-за ограниченного использования слова *пара*, исконное значение которого многими не воспринимается, даже после объяснений. И, если кому-то захочется блеснуть знанием редких слов, он может смело употребить «пара сапог» как не вызывающее отторжения. Услышанное, оно не будет воспринято всерьёз (вроде как закавыченное), а на письме про него забыли, как выглядит.

Comment: Я тут заминусовал по поводу "уместнее называть их турчанами".

Comment: Ответ вообще не тянет на ответ. Но — не вырубить топором. Нет аргументов. Впрочем, как и в вашем замечании.